# ts class - converting time stamps to numbers

Tags: r, time-series

I encountered a somehow strange behavior of the ts class regarding the storage mechanisms of the start and end time stamps. Example:

```
> K <- ts(c(1:10), start=0., end=1., deltat=0.1)
> start(K); end(K)
[1] 0 1
[1] 1 1
```

I get the start and end dates as natural time units, as described in ?ts. Sometimes I get the time stamps as single numbers:

```
> K <- ts(c(1:10), start=0.123, end=1.123, deltat=0.1)
> start(K); end(K)
[1] 0.123
[1] 1.123
```

Is there a way to force `ts` to store the dates as numbers and not as 2-vectors? Or, alternatively, is there a reliable method to convert the 2-vector representation to a number. I want to be able to retrive `t0` and `t1` out of `K` defined as

```
K <- ts(c(1:n), start=t0, end=t1, deltat=dt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tsp**. It does not store anything as 2-vectors -- it only represents it that way as the values of `start` and `end`.  `tsp(K)[1]` and `tsp(K)[2]` will give the start and end in the way you want.  See `?tsp` .

**zoo**. Another approach would be:

```
library(zoo)
start(as.zoo(K))
end(as.zoo(K))
```